# How to mock request module with rewire?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, request, mocking

I have a custom module **tokens.js** with a function which makes requests via **npm request module**. It looks like this:

```
'use strict';

let request = require('request');

module.exports.getToken = function(code, cb) {
  let url = 'some_url';

  request(url, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    } else if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      return cb('err');
    }

    parseGetResponse(body, function (err, token) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }

      return cb(null, token);
  });
});
```

I'd like to write **unit tests** to cover *getToken()* function, but I have some troubles with mocking request module.

I tried this:

```
let mocha = require('mocha');
let rewire = require('rewire');
let should = require('should');

let requestMock = {
  request: function (url, cb) {
      // return cb(); etc
  }
}

let tokens = rewire('services/tokens.js');
tokens.__set__('request', requestMock);
```

But this approach doesn't work:

```
TypeError: request is not a function
  at Object.module.exports.getToken (services/tokens.js)
```

Actually, it leads to another question:
*How request module may works without directly calling exported function **(request.request(url, cb))**? And how should I use rewire with this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to restructure the code so that its dependencies are easily configured.

```
function TokenGetter(request) {
   this.request = request || require('request');
   this.getToken = function(code, cb) { ...
}
module.exports.TokenGetter = TokenGetter;

// production code
var tokenGetter = new TokenGetter();
```

Test code

```
// test code can configure a mock request for your test, no 
// 3rd party libraries
// configure mockObject with assertions/return values
var mockRequest = function(url, cb) { .... ;

var testTokenGetter = new TokenGetter(mockRequest);
```

There are many strategies for making your classes configurable, and allowing the opportunity to inject fake objects for testing.  I believe striving to write code for testability should eliminate the need to add even more 3rd party dependencies to your project.

Comment: I didn't even think about DI approach in node.js. I'll try this way, thank you.

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952843/mock-module-which-does-not-exist/46954753 i want to mock the `meteor/meteor` location or in general the `import Meteor from 'meteor/meteor'`which is not present since i start my tests with `npm run mocha-tests` directly not with `meteor test`. Unfortunately lots of code is relying on the `Meteor` environment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a way to mock request module. I just make requestMock a function. Also I found out that in request module there is a line, that makes it possible:
**module.exports = request**