# mock module which does not exist?

Tags: node.js, meteor, mocking, mocha.js, mockery

When i run my mocha tests in my meteor app by:

```
node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register //..opts
```

i get a problem when my module under test wants to import:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
```

So i tried to mock it with mockery:

```
mockery.enable();
moduleUnderTest = '../moduleUnderTest';
mockery.registerAllowable(moduleUnderTest);
meteorMock = {};
mockery.registerMock('Meteor', meteorMock);
```

Unfortunately the module cannot be found

```
Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'
```

So the mocking of Meteor cannot be done.

Is there a way how i can fake the location `meteor/meteor`?
(Alternate Solution: If i can get access to the Meteor Environment in my mocha test)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery#registering-allowable-modules), you'll see that `.registerAllowable` takes a string, not a module. You also need to give the *exact module name that you are mocking*, and provide a fake module with the values you want.

So:

```
var mockery = require("mockery");

mockery.enable();
mockery.registerAllowable("./moduleUnderTest");
// We want Meteor to have the value "foo". You probably want something
// different.
var meteorMock = { Meteor: "foo" };
// We mock 'meteor/meteor' because that's what's imported.
mockery.registerMock('meteor/meteor', meteorMock);
```

If you think about it, what you were doing cannot work. You were requiring the module *before* Mockery is configured for mocking `'Meteor'`, so Node loads your module, and then tries to load Meteor before the mock is available, and you get a failure.

Moreover, Meteor mocks *modules* so when you register a mock, you have to give a *module* name, not the name of a variable.

Comment: yes, but that's why i ask for a way to fake the non present module

Comment: I'm not sure how that's supposed to be a reply to what I wrote. Yes, you want to fake a module that's not present, understood. I'm pointing out that you need to setup your mock *before* you run code that tries to load the non-existent module.

Comment: Ok got it now. Thx 4 the hint, but this should not be a problem since they do the same in their example https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery/blob/master/examples/example1.js I also tried with string before.

Comment: The code you are pointing to is doing exactly what I say you must do. For one thing, there's `moduleUnderTest = '../test/fixtures/intermediary'`. So yeah, they are using a string, and the order is the same as what I tell you to do.

Comment: True but it doesn't fix it. I have updated the code.

Comment: My initial answer focused on the elephant in the room but there was more that I missed. I've edited just now.